# Two form_tag on the same haml page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

routes.rb

```
 put '/', to: 'search#admin_action', as: 'admin_action'
 root 'search#index
```

search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def admin_action
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I have two forms under index.html.haml page
...

```
= form_tag({action:'index'}, {method: :get})
```

...

```
= submit_tag 'Search'
```

...

```
= form_tag({url: admin_action_path}, {method: :put})
```

...

```
= submit_tag 'Action'
```

All two submit buttons will be processed by index method in this case (never admin_action will be called). Actually, always action from first form is active for all below submit buttons. In erb files, maybe I can use some <% end %> to split these forms, but how to do that in haml file.

Comment: You might need to add some relevant code or files

Comment: what you have should work, two forms (not nested inside each other) pointing to the same URL.

Comment: Added relevant code. Two buttons to call two different actions.

Comment: Be very wary of indentation when using `haml`, that's the only thing really that could be messing this up for you.

Comment: Why don't you use block form of form_tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Form_tag* (under *haml*) doesn't generate `</form>` into final source. *form_for* works fine. To get correct final source, *form_tag* has to be use with *do*. So correct first line will be

```
= form_tag({action:'index'}, {method: :get}) do
```